# Using configureTestingModule with more than one spec file in Angular 6

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have two spec files, `test1.spec.ts` and `test2.spec.ts`.

Both use `TestBed.configureTestingModule()`.

When I run `ng test`, only the first file passes all of its tests and I get the error:

`Failed: cannot configure the test module when the test module has already been instantiated.`.

When I remove either of the files, the remaining file passes all of its tests.

I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: are you adding and removing spec files after running ng test?

Comment: @danday74 I am running ng test separately for each test. I ran it once for both, and once each for each individual file. Seems like the problem persists.

Comment: @danday74 I should clarify, I am using TestBed.configureTestingModule() in the beforeEach() method for each file

Comment: @michaelblxck Had you managed to solve this issue please? I'm running in the exact same error.